# Does the caster know when a spell with a variable duration ends?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spellcasting, duration

Does the caster know when a spell with a variable duration ends?

I'm looking for a RAW answer (answers based on Pathfinder or D&D 3.0 are ok if there is no info on this in D&D 3.5); I haven't found one here, nor in the rules.

For example, *time stop* has a duration of 1d4+1 rounds.

- Does the character only know that he has between 2 and 5 rounds?
- Does he know exactly how long he has, since the spell affects himself
  (i.e. if he rolled a 1, he knows he has 2 rounds)?

What about *color spray*, since it is cast on another person?

If there is no such info, how should I handle this as a GM?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I was still searching for the answer I found this:

**Timed Durations**

> Many durations are measured in rounds, minutes, hours, or some other increment. When the time is up, the magic goes away and the spell ends. **If a spell’s duration is variable the duration is rolled secretly (the caster doesn’t know how long the spell will last).**

[In the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm)

Comment: I'd also like to add that since you did practice the spell (might even had a mentor, for a spell like color spray) you SHOULD know that it would last 2-5 rounds (time stop).

Comment: So once it does end (at the end of a round) does the caster know that it has ended, or does he have to wait for secondary indications?

Comment: Well for time Stop it is obvious that it stopped since the flow of time will be back, color spray too since the creature will be able to act/won't be blinded/unconscious. There might be other spell that the caster won't know, if you cast color spray on a creature and flee, you won't know when it ended.